# Annotations for custom graphs in dask

Tags: dask

How can I specify resources per task in a [custom graph](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html) like you can achieve with the [`dask.annotate`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=GPU#resources-with-collections) context manager for dask collections?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the custom graph to a [High Level Graph](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/high-level-graphs.html#highlevelgraphs) object to add annotations.

Taking the example from the [custom graph docs that you linked](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html) to:

```
import dask
from dask.highlevelgraph import HighLevelGraph

def load(filename):
    ...

def clean(data):
    ...

def analyze(sequence_of_data):
    ...

def store(result):
    with open(..., 'w') as f:
        f.write(result)

dsk = {'load-1': (load, 'myfile.a.data'),
       'load-2': (load, 'myfile.b.data'),
       'load-3': (load, 'myfile.c.data'),
       'clean-1': (clean, 'load-1'),
       'clean-2': (clean, 'load-2'),
       'clean-3': (clean, 'load-3'),
       'analyze': (analyze, ['clean-%d' % i for i in [1, 2, 3]]),
       'store': (store, 'analyze')}


with dask.annotate(test="value"):
    dsk = HighLevelGraph.from_collections("test", dsk)
```